# Can same work be present in the worker pools of two CPU at the same time?

Tags: linux-kernel, worker, interrupt-handling

Normally a new work is queued in worklist of the CPU on which the issuer  was running.Can same work be queued in two worklists belonging to different CPUs at the same time? Is there any restriction on work like tasklets have ,i.e., Same tasklets can't run simultaneously on different processors.